# Using TSX with WebAssembly

Tags: webassembly, transactional-memory, intel-tsx

it is possible using TSX-Transactional Synchronization Extensions with WebAssembly?
I didn't find anything about using those extensions in WebAssembly.
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope that is impossible. This is i386 specific extension. So it is only possible to use it in actual WebAssembly implementation but not with WebAssembly moduls or any code targeting WebAssembly.

Comment: In other words, it could be utilized in a specific WASI player, or a browser optimized specifically for this instruction set, but generally not.

Comment: No you would utilize id to implement an WASI player or an browser the instruction set itself will hopefully never user in WASM code directly. But who says never they build custom JVM so why should they don't do it WASM as well.

Comment: I think there's a miscommunication here, Lee. I think we're saying the same thing.